# Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF' (Entando Framework)

Tags: node.js, json, entando

I'm studying [Entando](http://docs.entando.com/#current-release-notes) framework , following step by step the [Installing section](http://docs.entando.com/#installation).

I'm new to Node.

When I run the command `npm start` ([paragraph 3.3.1](http://docs.entando.com/#installation)), I get this error:

```
> app-builder@0.1.0 start C:\root_backup\workspace\entando app-builder\app-builder
> node scripts/start.js
Starting the development server...
Failed to compile.

./src/ui/common/form/RenderSelectInput.js
  Line 1:    Expected linebreaks to be 'LF' but found 'CRLF'  linebreak-style
```

I found some solutions on the Internet ([like this one](https://github.com/wellyshen/react-cool-starter/issues/105)), but it seems I can't apply to my scenario, since I can't find those files/scripts in my project.

Thank you for your precious help.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Hi @MaartenDev, what do you mean with "platform". Operating system?

Comment: Yes i meant the OS like mac or windows, line breaks differ per OS.

Comment: Windows 10. I read about the difference line breaks systems, but I couldn't find the way to solve the problem by editing package.json (as suggested on some topics). Anyway, with the solution I posted, it seems the problem is solved. Do you know if this is a good way to solve my problem? Thank you

Comment: What editor are you using? You could editor to use other line endings. This would prevent running the provided command every time.

Comment: I didn't use any editor. I didn't create any code line. I got this error when trying to launch Entando (a kind of CMS).
I got the error when  running the command npm start, after having cloned Entando from its repository on Github.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that with the command `npm run lint -- --fix` is fixed